# How to manually add data to form / request

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to add custom data to the form or request - for example **author_id** while saving my Post to database.

I've tried to do that by using:

```
$request->request->set('author_id', '5');
$request->request->set('post.author_id', '5');
$request->request->set('post[author_id]', '5');
```

But the problem is that when I `dd($request)` I see the following data:

[image]

So I should get inside the post array somehow and then put the author_id. How to achieve that?

In laravel I would do it like so `$request['post']['author_id'] = id;`

My actual function in controller looks like:

```
$post = new Post();
$form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);

$form->handleRequest($request);

$request->request->set('author_id', '5');

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

     $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $entityManager->persist($post);
     $entityManager->flush();

        ...
 }
```

What is the best way to add some custom data - not visible in the view (for example pass the user id) to the request or to directly to the form without displaying it (I am not talking about `display:none` attribute)?

Comment: $request->request->set('post.author_id', '5') or $request->request->set('post[author_id]', '5') not working?

Comment: Nope, I have tried both of your propositions right now.

Comment: i think for this problem you need use transformers http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: What if you try something like rebuilding the bag?- $pBag = new ParameterBag(); $pBag->add(['post' => [your array...], 'author_id' => 5]); $request->request = $pBag;  ?

Comment: Adding data to the request by hand sounds very weird. Why don't you just pass them to your model?

Comment: @Dimitris so give me an example in the answer below then to give me some clear view :)

Comment: Well the example depends on what you are doing with the data from the request. Are you handling the request with a Form to create an entity?

Comment: Basically I have Post entity, then I'm bulding the form with form builder - for that purpose I have the PostType and then I'm rendering the form in my view. Generally when I'm saving the post to database I want to set author_id and created_at timestamp values manually.

Comment: @Eakethet yes I can rebuild it like you said, but it look really complex but In my opinion there should be better and faster way to do so.

Comment: So after you do $post = $form->getData; you can just do $post->setAuthor($authorId);

Comment: @Dimitris you can look at the code right now in the question. You can suggest your thought in answer below.

Comment: Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request as a notion is supposed to be used as a read only bag of values passed by the user.

If you want to manipulate the data to save them to your database, you should do it in your model manipulation code

Based on the comments above, after you validate and check the form as submitted, you should do something like

```
$post = $form->getData();
$post->setAuthor($authorId);
$post->setCreatedDate(Carbon::now());
$entityManager->persist($post);
$entityManager->flush();
```

You can also move the created date setting directly to your entity constructor to avoid setting it yourself every time (Carbon is not necessary, you can obviously just pass it a plain datatime)

Comment: Hmm, yes it's good solution, but I have problem with validation - on my author_id column I have validation not blank so I cannot set the author id after validation.

Comment: You mean in your PostType? The author does not need to be in your PostType at all. It is always the user doing the post. The form type should include only fields that must be filled in by the user.

Comment: I mean that I have `@Assert\NotBlank()` in my Post entity. The `PostType` has only title and body fields.

Comment: You do not need that assertion. The authorId is an internally controlled variable, not something that you need to validate as user input. It should really be a non nullable manyToOne foreign key column to your User table.

Comment: Yea, ok then. Thanks!